# Expect/TCL Commandline Interact with same CLI where the script started from

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, tcl, expect

Using Expect/TCL and wanting to send a specific command to the same CLI I started the expect script from.

Not one of the following worked:

```
send "MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt \r"

exec "MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt \r"

exec "/Path/To/MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt \r"

send "/Path/To/MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt \r"
```

MyScript is the script i need and bla etc are additional informations for the call.

I need the expect script to use the same user and same directory like the one I started the expect script from.

Thx, G

Comment: We need more context to make sense of this, please show the whole script that lines you show are part of.

Comment: Is `\r` a carriage return/newline, or do you actually want to send a backslash followed by an r. If the latter, try `\\r` to avoid escaping issues

Answer (score 0):

To get the directory that contains the currently running script, use:

```
variable containingDirectory [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]
```

This should be placed *outside* any procedure. It will not work if you use a bash heredoc for the script, or rather it works *per se*, but the answer is completely useless; that's a case where things get rewritten behind the scenes to be in a totally different location so don't do that.

Once you have the directory, you can form names with either:

```
set filename $containingDirectory/MyScript
```

or:

```
set filename [file join $containingDirectory MyScript]
```

They're exactly equivalent on POSIX platforms.

Answer (score 0):

When using `exec`, you need to pass each part of the command as an individual argument, and you shouldn't include an end-of-line character:

```
exec MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt
```

If you want to use expect functionality, you can spawn a shell:

```
spawn sh
send "MyScript -bla blubber -super cmd.txt \r"
```

Both of these will run with the same current directory, environment, and user as when the expect script was executed, unless you purposely change that by using `cd` and/or `set env(ENVVAR) something` commands.

They will also both start a new subprocess, so they can't change anything in the process of the expect script.